# Screenlets not working in Ubuntu 16.04 ( Just Need analogue clock widget)

Tags: 16.04

The command that I tried are :

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

Result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package screenlets is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

Is there any other way to install it? I tried Using MacSlow's Cairo-Clock but that widget disappear after random interval of time. Is there anything else out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build and install it manually on 16.04 although some widgets are broken.  You will need Python 2.7 for this.

Download the source bundles:

1. [Screenlets Core](https://launchpad.net/screenlets)
2. [Screenlets Widget Pack](https://launchpad.net/indiv-screenlets)

Using *apt*, install **python-beautifulsoup, python-wnck, python-vte, python-tz**

1. Run **make install** in the two extracted paths.
2. Run **screenlets**

Or you can run through the following commands:

```
sudo apt install python-beautifulsoup python-wnck python-vte python-tz
cd /tmp
wget -O - https://launchpad.net/screenlets/trunk/0.1.6/+download/screenlets-0.1.6.tar.bz2 | bunzip2 -c - | tar xf -
wget -O - https://launchpad.net/indiv-screenlets/trunk/0.1.6/+download/indiv-screenlets-0.1.6.tar.bz2 | bunzip2 -c - | tar xf -
cd screenlets-0.1.6
sudo make install
cd ../indiv-screenlets-0.1.6
sudo make install
screenlets &
```

**NOTE:** You might run into a *Python* packages permissions problem, I fixed it by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R go+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked for me except that i had to manually set the PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: is there an easier way to install Screenlets?

Comment: I am getting this: 
File "/usr/share/screenlets-manager/screenlets-manager.py", line 34, in <module>
    import screenlets
ImportError: No module named screenlets

Comment: @MubasharAbbas Just set the pythonpath manually to the folder as I mentioned.

Comment: @HemantYadav is that a command or do I need to put it in a file or something?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas I would put `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` as a line in your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files, or if you are the only user on your system, use `/etc/profile` instead.