# How to remove screenlets from ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, screenlets

I have installed screenlets as the instructions given in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/801647/553971),I've launched it, it appears on task bar for a while with the sand glass and then disappears. So I wish to remove it completely.

Is there any command-line to remove the entire package? And Is there any alternative to this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

`sudo apt-get purge python-beautifulsoup python-wnck python-vte python-tz`

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

`sudo apt autoclean`

This should remove the python packages you installed at first.

And then run:

`sudo rm -r /tmp/indiv-screenlets-0.1.6`

To remove the Screenlets files.

Comment: But the icons are still appearing in the "Search your computer" Launcher Panel. How to get rid of that?

Comment: Run the last command again, I just edited it. @GaganCJ

Comment: I used your last code for removing the .py files, .sh files and the icons in /share/application and /usr/bin

Comment: Is there any alternative to screenlets (Don't Recommend gDesklets or conky ) @M. Becerra